# Why hot without neutral going downstream

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I have an outlet for the air conditioner, not GFCI.
I purchased a GFCI outlet (Leiviton GFWT2) to replace it (the outlet was old, with marks and painting).
Upon opening, to my surprise, there are two hots and no neutral. The neutral is connected to ground with a short wire, to make the outlet work. It has been working like that for years.

I researched about these two hots. One is hot from a (most likely) dedicated breaker labeled "AC", but was not used (!). Turning on the "AC" breaker, brings power to that hot end. No other outlet in the whole apartment is affected by this "AC" breaker, only this hot end (and it was off all this time). The other one is also hot but coming from another circuit breaker labeled "Living Outlets". This "Living Outlets" hot end was the one installed in this AC receptacle (and neutral connected to ground as I said previously).

Questions:

- I assume this was a totally wrong installation, correct? You can't just connect neutral to ground (even though it works).
- To make it worse, I have no idea why two hots ended up there. If there was one already, and it is working (the "AC" circuit breaker), why did they put another hot there (from the "Living Outlets" breaker). Any idea? Since there is no neutral anyway, the "AC" circuit breaker seems to have been a better option since it's dedicated.
- I read that a GFCI outlet might be OK to be installed in this case (with no neutral wire available) - is that right? If this is correct, what would be the correct way to "connect" the neutral?
- If I misunderstood about the GFCI outlet with no neutral available, then the only option is to bring the neutral all the way from the breaker? Because as far as I know I can't take a neutral from a nearby outlet, it has to be a neutral from the same circuit (either "AC" or "Living Outlet" breakers). I would rather not "extend" the Living Outlet circuit to the AC (even though this is how it was working). To make it worse, pulling any new wire would be a headache because conduits seem to be on their accepted limit already. Would require a full rewire probably.

Picture of box (sorry you don't see much, but I assure you there is only one conduit arriving, with two red wires; I added label so I know from which circuit is each wire):
[image]

Picture of the outlet, neutral side (you see the wire connecting it to ground):
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Yikes! What a mess. A number of different problems, including that if the ground (which shouldn't be used as neutral, but in *theory* could function (illegaly))  is not paired with the correct hot then you end up with a real mess. **Upload pictures, of all the wiring, maybe there is something one of the experts can figure out to fix it.**

Comment: This sounds like a major SNAFU without the N.  Picture of outlet will help, but I would be turning off main breaker and checking everything else in the place.  If they F..K this up, what else did they F..K up?  Are hots on same side of outlet or different sides?  You do know what happens to people who think they are working on a dead circuit, that is live?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box in question please? Also, what voltage do you measure between the two hot wires? I suspect this may be a very not-Code 240V outlet setup...

Comment: This is your first receptacle.  2  hots on a receptacle are perfectly normal. 1 from the supply, and 1 onward to the next receptacle.  The neutral situation, however, is bizarre.

Comment: @crip659 The picture won't help because it's one conduit arriving in the box, with two red wires. I confirmed both wires are hot in different circuits ("AC" breaker and "Living Outlets" breaker). It's not the first receptacle, in fact it is the last. These wires (both hot) end there, they don't go anywhere else. They are not connected together (thankfully!), they are hot of separate circuits. One was unused, and the other was hot for the receptacle (the neutral was connected to ground, to make it work).

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica  OP said the two hots were from different breakers, not one going to other stuff.

Comment: @crip659 I checked everything else, in fact this is the last outlet to replace. I did notice hot wires travelling downstream, and now I know where they end. With no neutral.

Comment: @igorjrr  A picture will still help in seeing how bad this is.  Hot and neutral side of outlet.

Comment: @crip659 added. Inside the box I assure you there is only one conduit arriving, with these two red/hot wires. One hot from "AC" breaker, the other hot from "Living Outlets" breaker. No neutral.

Comment: They are using the ground return for neutral, very bad.  That is a jumper wire from neutral to ground.  Is the tab connecting the two hot side screws removed at least?

Comment: @crip659 There is only one hot side screw. It's just one outlet, not two-in-one receptacle.

Comment: @igorjrr -- can you trace the wiring path back up to the box where this is fed from?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that would be my next move, but I first wanted try to answer the questions I put in the post (to the best extent possible). There are around 3-4 outlets, and one is a little hard to reach (behind heavier furniture)

Comment: OK, I get it.  This was an air conditioner outlet.  It was originally wired for 240V (two hots no neutral).  Air conditioners got more efficient, so one day Bozo got a 120V model, and did the laziest thing possible to power it up.  Power comes off one hot.  Neutral goes to the recep ground screw, to the receptacle yoke, through the mounting screws, to the metal conduit, back to the panel, and through the neutral-ground bond.    Wow, that's yiffed up...

Comment: So there are two black conductors that go to the panel. One of the black conductors could be used as a hot and the other a neutral by disconnecting it from a breaker and moving it to the neutral bar, but does code allow use of black wire as a neutral if it would be marked with white tape?

Comment: @JimStewart They are not black, they are red. One it seems go to panel ("AC" breaker), but the other is coming downwards from other receptacles ("Living Outlets" breaker/circuit). If I have to open the panel (which seems to be the case here, with an electrician), then I'd rewire the whole thing... (old wires).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica So I learned one more today, thank you. Makes sense. It's a building from 1956, so most likely it was a 240V outlet (two hots from different breaker, no neutral). Poorly converted to 120V. So my options is to rewire it using neutral from Living Outlets circuit (potentially overloading the whole living room outlet circuit) or call an electrician to properly pass neutral from "AC" breaker to that receptacle - but that requires rewiring everything since wires are old and it would not be possible to fish another wire without damaging existing ones. Time for an electrician.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like at one time this was a 240v circuit but it’s not now and you need a proper neutral.

Get some white or gray paint, or tape and coat both ends of the old cloth braid.
In the panel move the wire from the breaker to the ground buss (if a newer panel and the grounds and neutrals are separated to the white or grounded buss).

Then use the neutral at the receptacle. Break loose the neutral to ground jumper at the receptacle.

Connect the receptacle green screw to the box with a jumper wire or if self grounding receptacle the screw and box contact is all that is required.

These changes will make it much safer than using the conduit for a return path.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to re-color a live wire to neutral.